# Is it possible to set custom shortcuts for Styles Editor in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-dev-editor

In spite of that the Style Editor returns you a hint when you start typing a style name or value, it is quite annoying and time consuming to type styles in the editor without shortcuts when you edit for a long time. Is it possible to set custom shortcuts for Styles Editor?

For example,

```
pr [Enter or Tab or Shift+Enter or ...] => padding-right;
db [Enter] => display: block;
fl [Enter] => float: left;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible at the time. However, there is a feature request filed for the shortcuts in the styles panel: [crbug.com/360242](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=360242)